# Getting a c++ syntax error for a template stack implementation

Tags: c++, templates, syntax-error

I get a syntax error for this code, a c2143 error, the visual studio says the error is in the 7th line inside the class node definition.
if someone can please tell me what the error is I just don't get it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Node
{
    friend LinkedStack<T>;
    private:
    T data;
    Node<T> *link;
};
template<class T>
class LinkedStack {
    public:
        LinkedStack() {top = 0;}
        ~LinkedStack();
        int IsEmpty() const {return top == 0;}
        T Top() const;
        LinkedStack<T>& Add(const T& x);
        LinkedStack<T>& Delete(T& x);
    private:
        Node<T> *top; 
};
    template<class T>
LinkedStack<T>::~LinkedStack()
{// Stack destructor..
    Node<T> *next;
    while (top) {
        next = top->link;
        delete top;
        top = next;
    }
}
template<class T>
T LinkedStack<T>::Top() const
{// Return top element.
    if (IsEmpty()) cout<<"Stack empty:";
    else
        return top->data;
}
    template<class T>
LinkedStack<T>& LinkedStack<T>::Add(const T& x)
{// Add x to stack.
    Node<T> *p = new Node<T>;
    p->data = x;
    p->link = top;
    top = p;
    return *this;
}
    template<class T>
LinkedStack<T>& LinkedStack<T>::Delete(T& x)
{// Delete top element and put it in x.
    if (IsEmpty()) 
    {
        cout<<"Stack empty";
    return *this;
    }
    x = top->data;
    Node<T> *p = top;
    top = top->link;
    delete p;
    return *this;
}


void main(void)
{
    int x;
    LinkedStack<int> S;
    S.Add(1).Add(2).Add(3).Add(4);
    cout << "Stack should be 1234" << endl;
    cout << "Stack top is " << S.Top() << endl;
    S.Delete(x);
    cout << "Deleted " << x << endl;
    S.Delete(x);
    cout << "Deleted " << x << endl;
    S.Delete(x);
    cout << "Deleted " << x << endl;
    S.Delete(x);
    cout << "Deleted " << x << endl;
}
```

Comment: ...and the full error is? In general you want to include the exact error you get, not your own description of it.

Comment: `void main`... :'(

Comment: Above comments are right, especially @Bart's one. The complete error message is always a good idea : even if you don't get it (yet), the compiler tells you what's wrong :)

Comment: "`cout<<"Stack empty:";`" `throw "Stack empty:";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
friend LinkedStack<T>;
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
friend class LinkedStack<T>;
```

?

Comment: Don't know why this answer was downvoted, it's correct, meanwhile I wouldn't bet on @parapura's one.

Comment: MSVC allows the "class" to be omitted. It's not actually legal though.

Comment: @StilesCrisis: thx! I was testing with g++ so this was actually part of the answer for me. To my mind (I don't know if it was your vote, so don't feel targeted), a downvote should always be followed by a comment explaining why.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote. It's not legal, and MSVC should follow the standard better.